# add spaces in between String: Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to add a white space in between an inputted string and, although the code works, when I try to use the map function in conjunction with the code, it gives a pattern match failure when it hits the whitespace, any way I can ignore the whitespace or improve the code?

```
whiteSpace xs 
    | length xs <= 1        = xs
    | otherwise             = take 1 xs ++ " "++ whiteSpace (drop 1 xs)
```

Comment: "when I try to use the map function in conjunction with the code" - I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: Do not use `length xs`. It will loop in case it is an infinite loop. Furthermore it will blow op memory in case the list can be processed by using a list.

Comment: Sorry, by that I mean when I do (map letter (whiteSpace n)) for example, it fails at the space

Comment: @AdenGFX: what i letter doing here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem letter is a preset list of strings that when printed produces an ascii letter, e.g (letter 'A') will produce A in ascii characters

Comment: Oh. I understand what you mean by `map` now. You likely want to use `concatMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to implement `Data.List.intersperse`

```
> intersperse ' ' "asdfasd"
"a s d f a s d"
```

a basic implementation for your use case can be

```
> let white :: String -> String
|     white []     = []
|     white [x]    = [x]
|     white (x:xs) = x:' ':white xs
```